# Можно ли с помощью CSS добавить стили после определенного слова

Tags: css

Всем привет, есть такой код:

```
<h1>Название товара <span class="googd">хороший красивый товар</span><h1>
```

Нужно убрать тег <span> из <h1> и каким-то образом применить отдельные стили к "хороший красивый товар".   Возможно ли такое на CSS?  JavaScript не подходит, будет мигать.

Comment: _«Возможно ли такое на CSS?»_ - нет: CSS-селекторы работают только с элементами и псевдоэлементами (голый текст выбрать ими нельзя).

Comment: Непонятен контекст задачи. Если «Название товара» — это постоянная  повторяющая подстрока во всех заголовках, то можно её сделать псевдоэлементом. Тогда внутри <h1> не будет вложенных элементов, а слова оформлены по-разному.

Comment: @yar85, некоторыми псевдоэдементами все-таки некоторый текст выбрать можно, например [::first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) и [::first-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line)

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за инфу, про второй я не знал (хотя он аж с CSS2 существует o_〇)